# ConTeXt, HTML source code side by side to the result from the web

Tags: context, html

I would like to write a document with some HTML code and next to it the result from  a webpage.

Basically something like

```
\starthtmlexample
  <strong>Hello</strong>, <em>world<em>
\stophtmlexample
```

Would print the code highlighted side by side to the result of how it looks in a website.

What I have in mind is that the environment

- creates a new file for each example with .html extension where it stores some code that goes before the contents of the environment;
- then the contents of the environment, in this case `<strong>Hello</strong>, <em>world<em>`;
- some post html tags to close the file;
- then process the file with a command

  ```
  firefox -screenshot "screenshot-\n.png" "file:///Users/blah/blah/file-\n.html"
  ```

  (well, with options `--window-size="\certainwidth,\certainheight"`) to get a .png
- then add side by side the code (colored with `\usemodule[vim]`) and the image of the results.

Here's a “mockup”

```
\starttext

Something like

\starthtmlexample
  <strong>Hello</strong>, <em>world<em>
\stophtmlexample

should do something like

%             here v pre code
\startbuffer
  <html>
   <strong>Hello</strong>, <em>world<em>
  </html>
\stopbuffer % here ^ post code

% save this buffer to a file, say, htmls/html-1.html
% take a screenshot and save to screenshots/screenshot-1.png

\startxtable[option=stretch]
  \startxrow
    \startxcell
      \typehtmlfile[htmls/html-1.html] % this seems buggy
    \stopxcell
    \startxcell
      \externalfile[screenshots/screenshot-1.png]
    \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

And to be clear, I'm relatively new to ConTeXt, so this might be solvable with other systems, and this is an X Y problem.

My idea is to write a document with many small examples of html code.

Comment: Looks like a job for [`filter`](https://github.com/adityam/filter).

Comment: Thanks, yes, it looks like it :) Not able to make it work, but working on it. Nice to see this things exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot install webkit2png, so here is an illustration of how to do this using `pandoc` to convert `html` to `pdf`. First, let's start with the basic feature of showing both the source. Note that you need a local directory call `html` for this to work.

```
\usemodule[filter]

\startbuffer[before-html-example]
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body style="line-height: 1.5; font-size: 30">
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[after-html-example]
  </body>
  </html>
\stopbuffer

\traceexternalfilters

\defineexternalfilter
    [htmlexample]
    [
      directory=html,
      bufferbefore=before-html-example,
      bufferafter=after-html-example,
      output=\externalfilterbasefile.pdf, 
      filtercommand={pandoc -f html \externalfilterinputfile\space -o \externalfilteroutputfile},
      purge=no,
      cache=yes,
      readcommand=\DisplaySourceAndOutput,
    ]

\def\DisplaySourceAndOutput#1%
    {\typefile{\externalfilterinputfile}
     \externalfigure[#1][frame=on,width=10cm]}


\starttext
Hello
\starthtmlexample
  <strong>Hello</strong>, <em>world<em>
\stophtmlexample
\stoptext
```

[image]

Now, let's add syntax highlighting and remove the before and after code from the displayed code snippet. So, we change the definition of `\DisplaySourceAndOutput` as follows:

```
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping[html][syntax=html,directory=html]

\def\DisplaySourceAndOutput#1%
    {\typehtmlfile[start=6,stop=-2]{\externalfilterinputfile}
     \externalfigure[#1][frame=on,width=10cm]}
```

The value `start=6` asks `typehtmlfile` to show the output from the `6th` line (because `before-html-example` has 5 lines). The value `stop=-2` asks not to show the last 2 lines (because `after-html-example` has 2 lines).

The above example now gives:

[image]

Now all you need to do is modify `\DisplaySourceAndOutput` as you want it to be displayed.

### EDIT

I don't understand what you mean by the comment:

> For example to allow for `\starthtmlexample ... \realhtmlexample ... \stophtmlexample` or something like that.

Assuming that you want to ignore part of the environment, that is actually relatively easy (if you use buffers). For example, here is code to delete everything before the string `!!START!!` in the buffer:

```
\startluacode
  filterdata = filterdata or {}

  local ctxcatcodes  = catcodes.numbers.ctxcatcodes


  filterdata.pre_process = function(name)
    local content = buffers.getcontent(name)
    content = string.gsub(content,'^.*!!START!!',"")
    buffers.assign(name,content, ctxcatcodes)
  end
\stopluacode

\starttext
Hello
\startbuffer[demo]
  Stuff which is ignored
  !!START!!
  Stuff which is not ignored
\stopbuffer

\ctxlua{filterdata.pre_process("demo")}

\typebuffer[demo]

\stoptext
```

Comment: Okey, right now this works. Still it would be nice if there was a way to pre-process the buffer contents inside tex before exporting and processing with the filtercommand. For example to allow for `\starthtmlexample ... \realhtmlexample ... \stophtmlexample` or something like that. Also, is there a way to output the contents of the code like in a table, with some cell for the text and then a second cell in the same row to put the image?

Comment: `xtable` does not work inside a macro. You can try the simpler `\placesidebyside{...}{...}` or natural tables. If you really need the features of `xtables`, then using `\startsetups ... \stopsetups` should probably work.

Comment: And how could I hook that lua code before filter saves the buffer to a file? Also I would love if I could have the same behaviour as `strip=yes` after that `!!START!!`.

Comment: Simply use `\processhtmlexamplebuffer[demo]`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer as a work-in-progress of what I'm trying to achieve, with the suggestion of Henri Menke of using [`filter`](https://github.com/adityam/filter) module, in company with [`webkit2png`](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/).

At the moment this “just works”. But it's far from the definitive. I'll leave it here until (hopefully) someone writes a better and more complete answer.

Things that I hope I can change:

- save every extra file (from `filter`, `vim`, and `webkit2png`) in an `folder/` so that the current directory is not polluted;
- This one is solved through some hacks in the bash commands.

  <s>have some “pre” and “post” code so one does not need to write everything (for example now I need to write `<html><body>` etc.), ideally the input would be for example</s>

  ```
  \starthtmlexample
    <strong>Hello</strong>, <em>world</em>
  \stophtmlexample
  ```
- manage correctly the sizes of the image, and the fonts, and everything. Right now it's very fragile (I've done by hand the adjust of `font-size: 30` in the webpage).
- add some options to configure each example individually:

  - for example if we want examples side by side (for small examples), something like `\starthtmlexample[sidebyside]` or `\starthtmlexample[sidebyside=30]` or something like that to say what part is for the code and which part for the image, and also another option to show first the code then below the result;
  - options to change the pre-code, and post-code for an individual piece;
  - some way of altering what's shown and what's written, for example

    ```
    \starthmlexample
      <p> Lorem ipsum ... </p>
    \realhtml
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
        irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
     \stophtmlexample
    ```
- an inline way of doing this that ends up working in kind of tables:

  ```
  \startxtable
    \startxrow
      \inlinehtmlexample{<b>bold</b>}
    \stopxrow
    \sartxrow
      \inlinehtmlexample{<i>cursive</i>}
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtable
  ```

  to align many small results one below another.
- right now I can't remember more things I thought (the `frame=on` is jut to know what's happening at the moment, that I don't actually know many things I'm using here); and of course
- get a decent base design so that it looks better than the default I wrote.

Here's the code:

```
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping
  [html]
  [syntax=html,
   directory=auxfiles,
   before={\blank\setupbodyfont[small]},
   after={\blank},
   lines=split]

\startbuffer [before-html-example]
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body style="line-height: 1.5; font-size: 30">
\stopbuffer

\savebuffer [before-html-example] [before-html-example]

% \startbuffer [left-html-example]
% 
% \stopbuffer
% 
% \startbuffer [right-html-example]
% 
% \stopbuffer

\startbuffer [after-html-example]
  </body>
  </html>
\stopbuffer

\savebuffer [after-html-example] [after-html-example]

\usemodule[filter]

\defineexternalfilter
  [htmlexample]
  [%directory=auxfiles, % this doesn't work as (I) expected
%  input=\externalfilterbasefile.html, % this doesn't exist, but may be should?
   output=\externalfilterbasefile-full.png, % because of how webkit2png works
   filtercommand=\htmlfiltercommand,
   readcommand=\htmlexamplereadcommand,
   cache=yes,
   indentnext=no]

\def\htmlexamplereadcommand#1%
  {\bpar\typehtmlfile{\externalfilterinputfile}\epar
   \bpar\externalfigure[#1][frame=on,maxwidth=.5\textwidth]\epar}

\def\firefoxpath{/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS}
\def\chromepath{/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS}

\def\htmlfiltercommand
  {\htmlconcatenateparts\htmlobtainpng}
\def\htmlconcatenateparts
  {cat "html-before-html-example.tmp" "\externalfilterinputfile" "html-after-html-example.tmp" > "tmp.html";}
\def\htmlobtainpng
  {webkit2png
   %--dir="auxfiles" % doesn't work correctly with externalfilter
   --fullsize
   --width=1 % to get the minimum
   --height=1 % to get the minimum
   --scale=1 % unused
   --filename="\externalfilterbasefile"
   "tmp.html";}

% {\firefoxpath/firefox
%  -screenshot
%  "\externalfilteroutputfile"
%  "\externalfilterinputfile"}

% {\chromepath/Google\ Chrome
%  --headless
%  --screenshot="\externalfilteroutputfile"
%  "\externalfilterinputfile"}

\starttext

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\starthtmlexample
  <strong>Hello</strong>, <em>world</em>
\stophtmlexample

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\starthtmlexample
  <pre>
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   <b>Forever,</b><br/>
     8   9  10  11  12  13  14      and ever.<br/>
    15  16  17  18  19  20  21
  </pre>
\stophtmlexample

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure \inlinehtml{<b>alo</b>} dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Comment: For `directory=output` to work, you need to create the directory on your own.

Comment: For adding before and after content, search for `bufferbefore` and `bufferafter` in the documentation of the filter module

Comment: I see, still it doesn't work entirely well (or as expected) with `webkit2png` so I decided not to use it. And `bufferbefore` and `bufferafter` is of no use, because I want to input certain things, and then print those things while processing a different one. For now I think I could rely on bash commands, but I wrote this question in case someone showed a nice solution that is entirely ConTeXt / Lua, rather than hacks here and there.

Comment: Does `webkit2png --filename=html/test.tmp html/test.png` work from the command line? If so, then it should also work from within the filter module. Regarding `bufferbeforr` etc, I don't understand what you mean by _print those things while processing a different one_. Can you give an example?

Comment: I updated the answer. Well, the idea is to write in the example only a part of the whole file that is processed. So if I write `\starthtmlexample <b>bold</bold> \stophtmlexample` I want the file to be processed to have `<html><body><b>bold</b></body></html>` for example.

Comment: And about `webkit2png`, yes, it works, but if you write `--filename=html/test` it will output a file called `test-full.png` inside `html/` folder, but to do that symbolically right now I can't (I've to hardcode the folder) because I can't use `\externalfilteroutputfile` (which includes the folder automatically) so I would have to use: `--filename="html/\externalfilterbasefile`, which hardcodes the folder in a sense. *May be this should work, but then I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because I can't make it work.*

Comment: `\externalfilterbasefile` gives you the name of the file without the directory and the extension. It is difficult for me to test because I cannot install `webkit2png` on my desktop.

Comment: I added an answer to show how to get before and after buffer to work.